# StyleSheetRegistry refresh all (and/or some)

Tags: react-native

I have created my `StyleSheet`'s but having theming in mind so my `StyleSheet`'s:

```
const CONFIG = {
    blue: '#19281a'
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   blah: {
       backgroundColor: CONFIG.blue
   }
})
```

Now I want to change my theme, so I change the value in `CONFIG` but now I want to refresh all (and/or some) StyleSheets. Is this possible?

Comment: you need to go with adaptive styles.There are some hooks available. may be one of example is UserColorTheme hook. It is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. The standard StyleSheet creates static stylesheets.

`react-native-extended-stylesheet` is what I ended up going with when I needed to do theming. It extends StyleSheet and adds additional functionality so migration is painless.

There are some caveats when changing themes/having to force re-render the entire app/losing state but these are fairly easy to work around.

https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet

Comment: Darn, thanks Travis especially for that recommendation!